# Content encoding failure in GZipped XSS GWT app

Tags: gwt, gzip, xss

I've a GWT application that is consist of multiple modules.

One of them works as a Widget for the others (So I am enabling Cross-site ref by adding linker for `xs`).
The communication with other modules done using `JSON`.

I've added a GZIP compression filter on all `*.js`, `*.css`, `*.html`.

The application worked well for a while but after some time, the app is goes down!

The Widget still works, although all other modules when accessed from G Chrome returns `Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.` (and in other browsers returns similar messages)

Any one have idea about why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to XSS or GWT.

The problem because JSTL c:import causes problems with GZIP